# Site not working properly after cloning live WordPress site into localhost (Xampp)

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, localhost

I have cloned a live Wordpress website into local environment (using xampp server), the main page of website is working `http://localhost/foldername`, but when I try to go any other link, it returns me to the `http://localhost/dashboard` url.

### I already changed:

- wp_config.php
- set the new domain in database
- set new username and password of database.

Thanks in advance for your nice directions.

Comment: Start a new wordpress site on your localhost and use wp migrate plugin to clone your site to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your wp-config.php file add the following two line

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');

In the place example.com put your path then run your url/wp-login
```